# PHP: функция strtr() некорректно меняет символы в строке

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Есть функция `strtr`, которая посимвольно меняет в слове буквы исходя из массива.

Но почему, когда в слове есть нуль, а в массиве замены присутствует дефис, то происходит некорректное преобразование? В каком-то случае нули заменяются на единицы, в другом случае вообще вырезаются.

Например:

```
$value = 'B1000';   // слово с нулями
$converter = array('-'> ''); // если есть дефис, то удалить
$tr = strtr($value, $converter);  
echo $tr;   // результатом будет  'B1111' - нули заменяются единицами
```

Другой пример:

```
$value = 'B1000';   // слово с нулями
$converter = array('-'> '_'); // если есть дефис, то заменить на _
$tr = strtr($value, $converter);  
echo $tr;   // результатом будет  'B1' - нули вырезаются
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это очень забавная и очень примечательная опечатка, на примере которой будет интересно разобрать, как работает в РНР приведение типов.

- Итак, мы забыли написать знак `=` при задании массива.
- В итоге у нас получилось выражение `'-' > ''` (во втором примере - `'-' > '_'`), которое возвращает булево значение.
- PHP прекрасно сравнивает строки, по кодам символов

  - для первого примера непустая строка всегда больше пустой, и поэтому выражение `'-' > ''` возвращает `true`
  - во втором примере код минуса 45, код подчеркивания - 95, то есть `'-' > '_'` = `45 > 95` = `false`.
- если при задании массива мы не указываем ключ, то он генерируется автоматически, начиная с нуля. То есть массивы для замены будут иметь вид

  - в первом случае `array (0 => true)`
  - во втором `array (0 => false)`
- при преобразовании булевых значений в строковые `true` становится единицей, а `false` - пустой строкой.

В итоге в первом случае нули будут заменяться на единицы, а во втором - на пустые строки, то есть, другими словами - вырезаться.

Также надо отметить, что этот случай наглядно показывает, насколько важной является *отладка кода*, при которой мы проверяем все промежуточные значения на соответствие ожиданиям. В данном случае достаточно вывести а экран содержимое массива `$converter`, чтобы увидеть причину проблемы и не возводить напраслину на честную функцию `strtr()`

Answer (score 1):

У вас синтаксис не верный в массиве, измените его и всё будет работать как надо:

```
$converter = array('-' => '_'); //Замените символ > на =>
```

Тогда ваш пример будет выводить правильный результат:

```
$value = 'B1000';   // слово с нулями
$converter = array('-' => ''); // если есть дефис, то удалить
$tr = strtr($value, $converter);  
echo $tr;   // результатом будет  'B1000'
```